# problem with breaker popping

Tags: lighting

not all the time, but sometimes when we turn our light off in our kitchen pantry, it triggers other lights to go out so we have to reset the breaker for those lights. This is a brand new custom homebut we can't seem to get the electrician back out to look at it. Any idea what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Is it an arc-fault circuit breaker (AFCI)? What type of light is it (incandescent, fluorescent, LED, CFL, etc.)? What type of switch is it (normal snap switch, pull chain, door switch, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

As Tester 101 said. It is a nuisance tripping AFCI (arc-fault) breaker. This is unfortunately quite common. More than likely there is no problem whatsoever.

Keep contacting the electrician or GC to come back and replace the breaker.